# Efficient algorithm for generating graph edges

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-geometry

Given a set of vertices with 3D spatial coordinates $\{\vec{v}_n\}$ of size $N$ and a maximum connection distance $d$, is there an efficient algorithm to find all the undirected edges connecting the vertices with distance less than $d$; loops are not considered. A naive approach would simply loop on all possible pairs, requiring $N(N-1)/2$ distance calculations. Is there an existing algorithm for finding all possible edges with scaling complexity less than $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$?

Comment: I think you need something like an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree although it's not totally clear to me that building up the data structure would be quicker than just the n(n-1)/2 calculation.

Comment: @gilleain thanks for pointing that out. I have realized this problem is equivalent to collision detection, which has existing algorithms that can run in O(N) when the points have a finite number of connected neighbors but will always have O(N^2) worst case performance.